# updated python3 now terminal wont start

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I have the standard Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. My default `python` pointed to Python 2. I then installed `virtualenv`:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
$ sudo rm -rf ~/get-pip.py ~/.cache/pip
```

And modified my `.bashrc` by adding these lines:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Everything was fine and I could make virtual environments, install packages, work in them, deactivate them, etc.

Then one day I decided to upgrade my Python 3 to Python 3.7 because I needed to use asyncio. I followed this [guide](https://jcutrer.com/linux/upgrade-python37-ubuntu1810).

I made the new Python 3 my default and all seemed fine until I tried to open a new terminal. I got a message about `virtualenv` not being installed and then got the command prompt. But it was dead - I could not type anything. I quit the terminal and now all I get is the word 'terminal' in the menubar with a little spinning circle for a little bit and then it disappears. 
I commented out the lines in `.bashrc` about `virtualenv` but no joy.

---

EDIT:
Using xterm I did this

```sh
cd /usr/bin

sudo rm python3

sudo ln -s python3.6 python3
```

and rebooted.

Now I got my terminal back. python3 points to python 3.6.7. But I'm afraid of switching the symlink to 3.7.

---

UPDATE:

Even disabling virtualenv in .bashrc, rebooting, and trying to switch back to python3.7 reproduces the problem. I can invoke python3.7 directly from the command line and see the python3.7.1 prompt >>> but it seems the system does not like it to be the default python3.

Comment: I noticed another detail. When I try to start terminal, another icon which is a stop sign (red circle with a white horizontal bar in the middle) appears. Clicking on it reveals a menu that says  ' aproblem occurred while checking for updates'

Comment: and below that the word 'show updates' that does nothing

Comment: One of the comments on the blog post you used says: "If you update Python to latest version (3.7.3 at the moment) on Ubuntu 18, your native terminal won’t load. This article is helpful but not completed!"

Comment: You might have to downgrade to the previous version of Python 3 you had. For the future, may I suggest using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) which entirely avoids messing with the system installation of Python?